# Import .def files in Cython

Tags: python, c, matlab, cython, vlfeat

*Short version:*

How to import `.def` files in Cython?

*Long version:*

I am writing a Cython wrapper for [VLFeat library](http://www.vlfeat.org).
So there are two parts a def of a Cython module a definition file with a .pxd suffix, containing C declarations that are to be available to other Cython modules, and an implementation file with a .pyx suffix, containing everything else.

The structure is quite simple. 
There's a `.h`, a MEX (provides an interface between MATLAB or Octave and functions written in C) and a C (contains actual algorithm implementation) file for a particular function in Vlfeat library.

`.h` translates to -> `.pxd`

CMEX translates to -> `.pyx`

There wasn't any deviations from the structure until now. 
There's a function vl_binsum for which there is a MEX file and a [.def](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/blob/master/toolbox/misc/vl_binsum.def) file. I am not sure how to declare the contents of the `.def` file in a `.pxd`. Or does it even require a declaration? I tried searching a lot but couldn't find any tangible solution.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like the vl_binsum.def file is just an implementation detail of the vl_binsum.c file so you can probably ignore it.

Comment: .def is used by msvc compiler on Windows by passing /DEF option to the linker. In gcc this should not be required.